# Is there a manual way of telling Spiderable to consider the page “ready”?

Tags: meteor

In my most recent Meteor app I'm using methods to fetch data from the server for my templates rather than subscriptions, and (I think?) this confuses the Spiderable package which don't seem to understand when the consider the page ready to render. The fetching of the data are in some cases bound to the templates in their onCreated callback.

So my question is: **is there some kind of manual way of telling the spiderable package that all methods/subs are done and all templates have finished loading?**

(For routing I'm using the flow router if that's of any importance.)

Comment: I know that Spiderable waits for all subscriptiptions to be marked as `ready()`, any chance of seeing the code you're using for your methods?

Comment: It's basically calling a method and returning some documents from various collections. I guess I could move it into a subscription instead, but if there was a way of using just plain methods along with spiderable it would be sweet!

Comment: In my brief experience, Meteor focuses on using the pub/sub model for moving data to the client.  You may be able to find a hack-ish way around it, but setting up a pub/sub is probably your best bet for getting it done right.  Either way, the code you're using would probably help.